# "Invalid conversion from throwing function to non-throwing function", trying to store a closure and it can't throw

Tags: swift

I'm creating a static site generator in Swift, and am coming up with the API for adding "readers" - which are responsible for converting a raw file, of an extension they support, to a Page instance.

```swift
import Files

public struct Reader {
  var supportedExtensions: [String]
  var convert: (File) -> Page
}

public extension Reader {
  static func markdownReader() throws -> Self {
    Reader(supportedExtensions: ["md", "markdown"], convert: { file in
      let contents = try file.readAsString(encodedAs: .utf8)
      return Page(slug: "", title: "", content: contents, html: "")
    })
  }
}
```

The problem here is the I get the error `Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(File) throws -> Page' to non-throwing function type '(File) -> Page'`, which makes sense; nowhere in `var convert: (File) -> Page` does it say it can throw, but the real problem is, that I can't add that either? So, how does one work with throwing closures, and store those closures as a property? Or can I simply not throw any errors in a closure?

Comment: Could you explain why you can't declare `convert` to throw? `var convert: (File) throws -> Page`

Comment: I simply had the `throws` keyword in the wrong location 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `throws` is in the wrong place:

```
static func markdownReader() throws -> Self {
```

`markdownReader()` cannot throw. It just returns a Reader. The throwing, if any is going to happen, will happen in `try file.readAsString`, which is inside the closure. The throw does not magically somehow filter up out of that closure definition to the place where it is defined!

So basically you have two choices. One is to declare that the closure type *can* in fact throw:

```
var convert: (File) throws -> Page
```

The other is: don't let the throw percolate up out of the closure. Catch it:

```
do {
    let contents = try file.readAsString(encodedAs: .utf8)
    return Page(slug: "", title: "", content: contents, html: "")
} catch {
    // ???
}
```

The problem then is that in the `catch` block you are still obligated to return a Page (unless you'd like to `fatalError` at this point, on the grounds that the file can't be read so we may as well die). So you'd have to make up a page with fake `content`, since you failed to obtain the contents from the File.

Comment: Thanks! The correct location of the `throws` keyword was the solution 

Comment: I personally think that the second solution is better, because why should Reader be dictating that the `convert` function has to throw? That feels like letting the tail wag the dog. But if you're happy, fine. :)

Comment: Because I don't want to deal with optionals, basically, and the entire stack uses throwing functions. Also you're not saying `convert` *HAS* to throw, but it can. And that fits perfectly in the rest of the stack.